# How to get the value from puppeteer Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, promise, puppeteer

Using node. This works well, but I am not sure how to extract the content from text. I would like to parse the text variable information.

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
    
    async function gatherContent(url){
        
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        
       const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="gatsby-focus-wrapper"]/div/header/h1/a');
        const src  = await el.getProperty('textContent');
        const text =  (await src).jsonValue();
          
        console.log( {text});       
          
        browser.close();    
    
    }

gatherContent('https://returnstring.com/articles/puppeteer-elements-and-values')
```

When I run node scrap.js it returns

{ text: Promise { 'Return String' } }

I need to extract the content of the Promise (Return String).

So I can do something like this.

const textAgain = text;

Comment: Change `const text = (await src).jsonValue();` to `const text = await (await src).jsonValue();`.

Comment: That worked your the best!

Comment: It works but it's easier to just remove the parens: `await src.jsonValue()`. The correct code is right on the page you're scraping. Also, best to use `.finally()` to close the browser so it'll clean up whether or not a throw occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The function `jsonValue` returns a promise, just like almost everything else in your code, so you have to add an additional `await (const text = (await src).jsonValue();` instead of `const text = await (await src).jsonValue();`).

When you log it again, you should actually get the promise value.

Comment: Or just use `await src.jsonValue()`. Awaiting the promise twice is pointless.